# Constant function returns empty array + web3js

Tags: web3js, metamask, geth-debugging, constant, angular2

I have a simple solidity script where I tested in remix (injected Web3 using geth local environment) and worked fine returning an array of data from a constant method.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract TestBetting {

  struct BettingInfo {    
      uint256 matchId;
      uint homeTeamScore;
      uint awayTeamScore;     
      uint bettingPrice;  
  }

  address public owner;
  mapping(address => BettingInfo[]) public bettingInfo;

 // constructor
  function MyBetting() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  // Fall back 
  function () payable {}

  event LogDeposit(address sender, uint amount);

  // Place a bet  
  function placeBet(uint256 _matchId, 
                    uint _homeTeamScore, 
                    uint _awayTeamScore, 
                    uint _bettingPrice) payable returns (bool) {

    bettingInfo[msg.sender].push(
      BettingInfo(_matchId, _homeTeamScore, _awayTeamScore, _bettingPrice)); 

    require(_bettingPrice == msg.value); 
    this.transfer(msg.value); 

    LogDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);

    return true;
  }

  function getBettingInfo(address _better) public constant returns (uint256[], uint[], uint[], uint[]) {
    uint length = bettingInfo[_better].length;
    uint256[] memory matchId = new uint256[](length);
    uint[] memory homeTeamScore = new uint[](length);
    uint[] memory awayTeamScore = new uint[](length);
    uint[] memory bettingPrice = new uint[](length);   

    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      matchId[i] = bettingInfo[_better][i].matchId;
      homeTeamScore[i] = bettingInfo[_better][i].homeTeamScore;
      awayTeamScore[i] = bettingInfo[_better][i].awayTeamScore;
      bettingPrice[i] = bettingInfo[_better][i].bettingPrice;   
    }

    return (matchId, homeTeamScore, awayTeamScore, bettingPrice);
  }
}
```

[image]

When I do this in angular 5 with Geth local environment, first I need to submit transaction through placeBet method.

```
submit(form: NgForm): void {  
    this.bettingPrice = 20;
    this.bettingPrice = this.web3.toWei(this.bettingPrice, "ether");

    this.TestBetting.deployed().then((instance) => {
        return instance.placeBet(this.matchId, 
                                 this.homeTeamScore, 
                                 this.awayTeamScore, 
                                 this.bettingPrice, {
            from: this.account,
            value: this.bettingPrice,
            gas: 50000
        });
      })
      .then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      }); 
  }
```

It will open up metamask and it looks like it went through.
[image]

Now, I want to call getBettingInfo to see the data I submitted into network.

```
  loadGetBettingInfo() {   
    this.TestBetting.deployed().then((instance) => {
        return instance.getBettingInfo.call(this.betterAddress, {
            from: this.betterAddress,
            gas: 50000
        });
      })
      .then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      }); 
    }
```

But this returns an empty array in the console.
[image]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the transaction was mined correctly? Perhaps you are calling getBettingInfo before the transaction is mined. Is betterAddress the same address that placed the bet?

Comment: Yeah I was mining with geth and I changed to Ganache and it works now. 
`geth --networkid 4224 --mine --datadir "..path" --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "...port #" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,miner,net --unlock 0 --password password.sec
` This was my geth command in which mine was enabled. Still don't know why it didn't work with that

Answer (score -1):

This is because`this.TestBetting.deployed().then((instance)` is creating the new instance every time which doesn't possess the previous state changes. So you need to create one instance and use it for all functions access.

Comment: `Contract.deployed()` does not create a new instance, it only returns a reference to the instance create with the migration scripts.